# How does recalling a blade from a mission work?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

If I try to engage a blade while they are on a Merc Group mission, I get a notice asking if I want to recall the blade from their mission.

How does recalling a blade work? Will recalling the blade recall the entire squad of blades or just the one blade I've selected? Will a recalled blade get any experience from their mission?

[image: prompt to recall a blade]

Comment: According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/7i4owe/a_guide_to_mercenary_missions_and_how_to_make_use/), "you can recall them immediately and forgo the reward with no other penalty". So I think the experience will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recalling a Blade will recall the entire party and cancel the mission without granting any rewards (ie: money, experience,
affinity chart progress).

Blades can be recalled either by engaging a blade that is on a mission (Characters > Engage Blades) or by selecting an active mission (Merc Group).